# Extending the TcpClient Class in the oscP5 Processing Library

Tags: processing, osc

I am trying to extend the TcpClient class in the [oscP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/oscP5/index.html) library for Processing.  I have already imported netP5.* and oscP5.* in my main sketch.  However, the following code produces this error:  **expecting TRIPLE_DOT, found ','**.  What is wrong with how I extended it?  Am I supposed to add all of those arguments in the constructor?

```java
class GameClient extends netP5.TcpClient {
int score;
//some more variables

public TcpClient(Object theObject, String, theAddress, int thePort) {
//This is the constructor.
}

//I want to override this function
public void dispose() {
  println("dispose() called.");
}

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please look at your example:

> public TcpClient(Object theObject,
>   String, theAddress, int thePort) {

you have a comma between `String` and `theAddress` which doesn't belong there.